# Вставка с сортировкой. C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть структура **Deal**:

```
struct Deal
{
   public string Date { get; set; }
   public string Time { get; set; }
   public string Priority { get; set; }
   public string Tags { get; set; }
   public string Comment { get; set; }
   public string AbsolutePathToFile { get; set; }
}
```

Основная задача - вставка и поиск.

Допустим, есть `List<Deal>`.

Исходя из задачи, я хочу вставлять объект `Deal` в  `List<Deal>` сразу в нужное место из-за того, чтобы операцию поиска я делал с помощью `BinerySearch` без предварительной сортировки.

Подскажите, люди добрые, какие нужны структуры данных и какие алгоритмы для этого.

Comment: А в чём смысл сортировки, вы будете искать не по подстроке, а по начальному вхождению текста? В принципе, тут могут пригодиться словари и хэши значений, но всё-равно задачу надо более чётко сформулировать. Если в списке не будут миллионы прямо записей, то можно и по всему списку искать каждый раз.

Comment: @CrazyElf, миллионов записей не будет, но хочется писать как можно более производительную прогу + на шарпе я такого не писал еще. Касательно того как я буду искать, я сам не знаю, поэтому спросил. Что я предположил - если отсортировать данные(опять же, по каким критериям - не знаю), можно будет использовать бинарный поиск.  К примеру, если отсортировать данные по дате, времени и приоритету, то поиск дел на конкретную дату или время, или приоритет был бы быстрый.

Comment: Используйте `List<Deal>`. Кстати у `List<T>` уже есть метод `BinarySearch()`, вам лишь надо реализовать у вашего класса `IComparer<Deal>`. С другой стороны вам лучше заморочиться изучением и применением [LINQ](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.1.php) в своей программе.

Comment: @Bulson, я с линком знаком, и он используется в других местах, но BinarySearch() из List<Deal> будет работать только в том случае, если он(List<Deal>) уже упорядочен, а он таковым не будет(специально сортировать не буду). Так вот я по этому и хочу добавлять с сортировкой, т.е. в нужное место, чтобы потом принудительно его не нужно было сортировать для бинарного поиска.

Comment: По своей сути проблема надуманна. Записей дел вряд ли будут миллионы, как вам уже выше заметили, потому поиск нужной записи займет ли 2 мл.сек. или 5-6мл.сек не заметит пользователь все равно. Это все экономия на спичках, и пустая трата времени. Что касается второго, то нужный ресурс нужно размещать в папке с exe.

Comment: @Bulson, хорошо, задам вопрос по-другому: если в программе предполагается использование БД с миллионом записей(дел), которые десериализованы в List<Deal>, то как осуществлять эффективный поиск дел по различным критериям? Как вариант - отсортировать миллион записей и потом использовать бинарный поиск. Но сортировка миллиона записей - очень затратный процесс. А если представить, что можно записывать в List<Deal> сразу по нужному месту, то и сортировать List<Deal> для бинарного поиска не нужно.

Comment: Когда речь заходит о БД и извлечения чего-то там и сортировка и поиск и проч., все это должно делаться строго силами сервера БД, он собственно для этого и служит. А не вытягивать к себе в прил. все данные, а потом что-то с ними делать в ОЗУ. Это глупо и непроизводительно.

Comment: @Bulson, я пытаюсь дать вам понять, что абсолютно не важно, миллион записей или 50, мне важно научиться писать эффективный алгоритм поиска, вставки и т.д. Поэтому я на примере этой задачи пытаюсь это сделать.

Comment: Извиняюсь, тогда ваш вопрос надо полностью изменить. Убрать тег `WinForms`. В заголовке убрать всякое упоминание о том же. Добавить тег `алгоритмы`. И сформулировать вопрос таким образом, что есть вот такая сруктура, и мне нужно реализовать такой-то поиск, по таким-то параметрам. Подскажите, люди добрые, какие нужны структуры данных и какие алгоритмы для этого.

Comment: @Bulson спасибо!

Comment: Непонятно что означает «нужное место». Составьте пример: начальное состояние списка -> новый элемент -> ожидаемое состояние списка после вставки.